# python instersection if statement

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

So I am doing a project where I try to guess the key of a message that has been changed. The message was converted from character to ascii number had the key added onto the ascii number and then converted back to character. I am struggling to figure out how to get a if statement that would return something if there is an intersection between the message and a word bank. It never returns the correct thing. Thoughts?

```
 import re
from list_maker import *
message = input("what is your code? ")
list_broken = [ord(i) for i in message]
key = 27
num = 26

for l in list_broken:
    key -= 1
    list_decoded = [chr(i - key) for i in list_broken]
    final = ''.join(list_decoded)
    word_list = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", final).split()
    S1 = set(word_list)
    S2 = set(set_of_words)
    i = 0

    for e in S1:
        if e in S2:
            break


print(word_list)
print(key)
```

Comment: On sets, intersection is the `&` operator. `if S1&S2: ...`

Comment: Or you can use `set.intersection(s1, s2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets have an intersection operator just for this.

`S1&S2` returns the set of elements in both given sets.

So for your case, you can just check:

```
if S1&S2:
    ...
```